# Errors in Apex Class - List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: apex

I want to add an apex message inside of my method that will showup if query returns a null value. Here is a bit of the code that includes query.

```
AccName = [Select Name, Customer_Account_Number__c 
             from Account where Customer_Account_Number__c =:uano limit 1].Name;

    if (AccName == Null) {
         ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning, ''));
                system.debug('Empty string');
     }
     else{system.debug('found acc name ');}
```

unfortunately when a user types in a wrong number an error message in a salesforce pages shows up and I'm trying to avoid that. What could a best solution for that be ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its always advisable to assign the query to a list and do the processing from the list.

So change this

```
AccName = [Select Name, Customer_Account_Number__c 
         from Account where Customer_Account_Number__c =:uano limit 1].Name;
```

to

```
List<Account> lstAccount = [Select Name, Customer_Account_Number__c 
         from Account where Customer_Account_Number__c =:uano limit 1];
if(lstAccount.size() > 0)
    AccName = lstAccount[0].Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to query for a record you aren't sure exists is to pull it down as a list:

```
List<Account> candidates = [/*query*/];
accName = !candidates.isEmpty() ? '' : candidates[0].Name;
```

Comment: Per OP context, accName is a String. So candidates[0].Name should be assigned to it.